# Firebase Firestore get data from collection QuerySnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from my Firebase Firestore database. please tell me where to fix code.
or Firebase new Version i can't use

I want to show Post RecyclerView on HomeFragment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MbwF.png)

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView blog_list_view;

    private List<BlogPost> blog_list;

    private FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private BlogRecyclerAdapter blogRecyclerAdapter;

    private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;
    private Boolean isFirstPageFirstLoad = true;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        blog_list = new ArrayList<>();
        blog_list_view = view.findViewById(R.id.blog_list_view);

        blogRecyclerAdapter = new BlogRecyclerAdapter(blog_list);
        blog_list_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext()));
        blog_list_view.setAdapter(blogRecyclerAdapter);

        mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mStore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                for(DocumentChange doc: documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){
                    if(doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                        BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
                        blog_list.add(blogPost);

                        blogRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Error HomeFragment Looking Picture

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: Please add the content of your `BlogPost` class. Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo